# Start Coroutine step-after-step in loop

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine, ienumerator

I have a list (called path) with GameObjects. The current GameObject (with the script attached) should move from one position of the GameObjects in the path to the next stepwise. My current code makes it move to the last position of the path immediately. I already tried with `WaitForSeconds` at the end of the Coroutine but as they are all started at once, it has no effect.

What can I do to get the step-after-step effect?

Here my code so far:

```
public List<GameObject> path;
private Vector3 start;
private Vector3 target;
private float lungeSpeed = .8f;
private float lungeDistance = 5;
private IEnumerator coroutine;

public void StartPath() {
        foreach (GameObject field in path) {
            start = transform.position;
            target = new Vector3(field.transform.position.x + lungeDistance, field.transform.position.y, field.transform.position.z);
            coroutine = MoveObject(start, target, lungeSpeed);
            StartCoroutine(coroutine);
        }
    }

IEnumerator MoveObject(Vector3 start, Vector3 target, float speed)
    {
        float t = 0.0f;
        float rate = 1.0f / speed;
        while (t < 1.0)
        {
            t += Time.deltaTime * rate;
            transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(start, target, t);
            yield return null;
        }
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now your code in `StartPath` isn't waiting on `MoveObject` to finish. You could solve this by running `StartPath` in a coroutine and have use `yield return MoveObject(start, target, lungespeed)`.

Still will stop the execution of the foreach loop in `startPath` untill `MoveObject` has finished with the `yield return new WaitForSeconds`

```
public IEnumerator StartPath() {
    foreach (GameObject field in path) {
        start = transform.position;
        target = new Vector3(field.transform.position.x + lungeDistance, field.transform.position.y, field.transform.position.z);
        coroutine = MoveObject(start, target, lungeSpeed);
        yield return StartCoroutine(coroutine);//this will keep the foreach loop from iterating untill the coroutine has finished
    }
}
```

also a little side note:

> (because the coroutine is executed in a new parallel thread)

Is incorrect. Coroutines do **not** run on a seperate thread. A coroutines runs on the main thread as all the rest of your code, it just does a little trick where it pauses and resumes execution based on your yield statements, but still on the main thread.

If you want to run something on a seperate thread you need to call  `new Thread()`. However this is a whole different piece of cake as thread cannnot inherit from Monobehaviour

Comment: Thanks for your note, I changed my question to remove the wrong information